# Fastest way to compare 2 c++ std::lists, changing in each iteration

Tags: c++

Let's say i have 2 std::lists, each contains various numbers of elements. Every element (on each list) has UNIQUE int id value. On every iteration i need to remove elements from first list that don't appear on the second one and add elements from the second list that don't belong to the first one. E.g (numbers=unique ids):

> 1. iteration: first[3,2,1], second[4,3,5,7,6], result: [3,4,5,6,7]
> 2. iteration: first[3,4,5,6,7], second[4,10,9], result: [4,10,9]

etc...
I cannot simply swap second one to first one (let us recognise it's impossible, too long to read).  My question is:
What is the best search algorithm I can perform to update first list? I mean, should i use nested loops on both sorted lists and compare ids? Remove continuously elements from first lacking in the second but also delete repeating ones in first. Then merge it? Or maybe make one of them unordered_map(hash table)?

Edited:

I wanted to simplify problem but in fact, it's unclear now. I cannot change  containers, there are 2 unsorted lists contain 2 different structures each. The only link between 2 types of structures is an id parameter. In every iteration i have to check if first list looks just like the second one. Ids are unique, no repeats allowed. So if ids match lists will be identical. I can't swap them because first list has e.g 30 values and the second one 10 (it's incompleted). There are another special functions to prepare structure for first list that consist of many different structures (including structure from list 2). These functions are launched only if there are ids from the second list that don't appear in the first list. I mustn't manipulate first list but i'm able to modify the second one.

I tried in this ways. In every iteration:

```
1. Create a std::unordered_set with hashed ids from second list. Then compare it to first list and remove outdated ids from first list. Remove also repeating ids from unordered_set. We'll end up with the set of new structures from list 2. We can run another functions and then add suitable ones to first list.

2. Sort list2 by ids. Then do binary search.

3. Linear search. 2 loops. Id that appears in first list and doesn't in the second one is removed from first list. Id that appears in both lists is removed from the second list. And finally we got ids that appear in second list and don't in the second one. We can process them and merge with list 1.
```

The most important thing: There will be a lot of comparisons but lists are the same most of the time!

Comment: 1. Why `std::list` over `std::vector` ? 2. Why use a sequence container at all? It looks like you want `std::set`.

Comment: 3. The result always seems to be exactly the same as the second list....

Comment: You are asking what the best solution is to do something but then you are saying, that there are further constraints, that make use of the optimal sulution (just copy second list) impossible. How is anyone supposed to make any other reasonable suggestion without knowing those constraints?

Comment: As you have described it the result is always the second list as @BillyONeal pointed out. However I suspect you may be after something like [std::set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference).

Comment: Also concur with the suggestion to use at least `vector` here. With unsorted linked lists, the range of algorithmic solutions narrows to brute force solutions passing over the entire data, since a linked list can only provide bidirectional iteration. Anything smarter than that over a linear sequence is going to require random access. Plus even if you're just using brute force, a contiguous sequence will still at least be faster at a micro-level due to spatial locality.

Comment: @ike: Not quite; `set_difference` works just fine with bidirectional iterators and `list::sort()` is supposed to be an efficient `O(n lg n)` merge sort. The main difference will be memory locality because `list` typically adds about 6 pointers of extra space overhead per element.

Comment: Ooh, list sort is nice. I didn't realize there was a linked merge sort there -- always used to `std::sort`. `set_difference` is perfectly fine but that's just a linear pass through already-sorted data, no?

Comment: I think a tricky part also with the micro-efficiency of a linked merge sort is constantly iterating towards the center of each sub-list. I'm used to seeing efficient linked merge sorts kind of bastardize the idea of a linked list and array together so that you got that O(1) random access to the center of the list and spatial locality, but still those list pointers to split them apart and merge them together again in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is probably going to be to simply assign the second list to the first:

```
first = second;
```

which will copy all the elements in second and put them in first.

If for some reason you need to keep the elements in place, you can sort each list and use the [`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) algorithm to find all the elements in one list that are not in the other list.